# Crontab executes python script but something is wrong

Tags: python, dictionary, cron, pygame

I am new to programming. I think I'm close to solving my issue, but it finally broke my brain and I need help.

I am running a pygame script as a scheduled task in crontabs. I have one code that executes successfully and does what it should. I have another code that executes, but when it does the screen goes blank, usually displaying some lines that I usually see when the Linux boots up, and it just stays stuck there.

I have gone through both codes and absolutely everything is similar and correct. I have `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the start of each script.
(Elsewhere it was recommended that I give the exact version, because I use dictionaries in my script and apparently crontab could get confused with the dictionary stuff that pygame uses. I don't fully understand, I tried it but it didn't work on my raspberry pi so I don't think that's the solution.)

Each script runs fine in the terminal.

I have set the PATH variable to the one that the python script uses and also set the SHELL to /bin/bash. In the task I also have "export DISPLAY=:0" (e.g. 12 21 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && ...). I have found this was the magic trick that got the other code to work. Which made me wonder if there is another environment variable that I need to set in the task?

The difference between the first code and the second code: The second code uses pygame.mixer and plays sound files. In the script, the sound files are in dictionaries (e.g. sound = {"word" : "/absolute/path/to/file.wav", "word2" : ...etc} As I said this code runs fine in terminal.

So why does the one script work and not the other. Both use pygame. The other just uses sound, dictionaries instead of strings, and pygame.mixer as well. My reasoning is that there is an issue with crontab getting stuck on one of these things.

Comment: write some information in file which will show you which part of code is executed and/or what you have in variables. Write also messages from `try/except`. Maybe this way you find where is the problem. Usually scripts in crontab make problem because they can run with different privilages (no access to some folders), as different user, starts in different folder (so they can't find other files)

Comment: As well as @furas suggestions - this diagnostic detail will also narrow down the problem in a way that will make it easier for stackoverflow to help. Outputting environment detail to a log - environment variables, time of execution etc - can also help, since the script runs fine when not through cron.

Comment: I have taken the old script (that works in Crontab) and tried adding things step by step, checking each step of it works in Crontab. When I add the line 'pygame.mixer.init()' Crontab can't run it anymore it seems. Or if I just try to add 'pygame.mixer.music.load("/path/to/file.wav")' and then 'pygame.mixer.music.play(1)' it also freezes up in Crontab. I'm thinking it struggles to get the sound file, like you said, maybe doesn't have access to the folders? How do check if this is the issue? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I was running it out of root. When I ran the crontab in the user it worked. It must be because the root couldn't get at the files.
Important tips is to add 'import os' and at some point in the script add 'print(os.environ)' to check all the environment variables when it runs in terminal.
Then copy the $PATH variables to the top of the crontab jobs.
Same with $SHELL.
The $DISPLAY variables need to be put in the line, so for example '* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/python /home/user/file.py'
See how I put absolute paths for both the command and the path to file. I also set absolute paths to files in the script, even if the files are in the same folder as the script. I'm not sure if this is necessary I will check that next. I've seen a lot of people struggle with this issue and the advice usually comes down to these things.